# Display image from backend on frontend (Flask on backend, JS frontend)

Tags: javascript, html

I have web application that getting image (BLOB file in SQL) and needs to show it on web page.

Here is full code of page. 1) form to submit request 2) JS to make request 3) JS code to catch response and show it in

```
<img id="image_data" src="">
```

here is info from developer mode so i see image there in preview (and nothing in response)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLosc.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Lazy board</title>
  </head>
  <script>
    function addNavBar() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("navbar").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "navbar.html", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="navbar"></div>
    <script>
      addNavBar();
    </script>
    <h1>Get picture</h1>
    <form id="getPicture">
      <label for="content_id">Content ID:</label>
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="content_id" name="content_id">
      <br>
      <img id="image_data" src=""> 
      <br>
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script>
      var form = document.getElementById('getPicture');
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var contentId = document.getElementById('content_id').value;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/getPicture');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
          var response = xhr.response;
          document.body.innerHTML += response;
          document.getElementById('image_data').src = response;
        });
        var formData = new URLSearchParams();
        formData.append('content_id', contentId);
        xhr.send(formData);

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tried many things. backends response looks like that and yes, in DB is png file that i can view also

```
        return Response(image_data, mimetype='image/png')
```

Comment: `in DB is png file` -- in code: `type: 'image/jpeg'`

Comment: it fixed bro, forgot to renew code here. i can see image in getPicture preview in developer mode, but still cant catch it no front

Comment: I added to script:         document.getElementById('image_data').src = response;
and trying to show it as image:       <img id="image_data" src=""> 
but nothing happens :( i updated first post

Comment: added           console.log(response); and it logged same thing that i see on page